# How to add an intent to a navigation view tab?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, view, tabs

So I have a navigation view that slides from the left with a tab called Bluetooth. I want that bluetooth button to connect with another class that has all the bluetooth functionality. Is there a way to and an intent pr something for me to connect to that functionality class? Sorry if I'm not really specific, I'm an Android Studio beginner.

My nav View with the button:
[image]

my main class:

```
public class PantallaDatos extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantalla_datos);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, 
    R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    ViewPager2 viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager2.setAdapter(new DatosPagerAdapter(this));

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(
            tabLayout, viewPager2, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy(){

        @Override
        public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {

            switch(position){
                case 0:{
                    tab.setText("Medidas");
                    break;
                }
                case 1:{
                    tab.setText("Registros");
                    break;
                }
                case 2:{
                    tab.setText("Graficos");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    tabLayoutMediator.attach();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

   }
 }
```

The class that has all the functionally which I want to connect to that button (simplified):

```
 public class AjustesConexionSensores extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
 private static final int REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;
 private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 11;
 private TextView mEstadoBlueTv;
 private ImageView mBluetIv;
 private ListView mLvEmparejados, mLvDispositivos;
 private Button mBotOnOff, mBotDescubrir, mBotEmp, mBotConectar;
 private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
 private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
//Conexión bluetooth
private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE = UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");
BluetoothConnectionService mBluetoothConnection;
//Dispositivo BT y ArrayList de dispositivos
BluetoothDevice mBTDevice;
public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

//BROADCASTS
// BroadcastReceiver para ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

            switch(state){
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    showToast("Bluetooth desactivado");
                    mBluetIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_off);
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                    showToast("Bluetooth activado");
                    mBluetIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_on);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ajustes_conexion_sensores);
    //Interfaz
    mEstadoBlueTv = findViewById(R.id.statusBluetoothTv);

    mBluetIv = findViewById(R.id.BluetoothIv);
    mBotOnOff = findViewById(R.id.BotOnOff);
    mBotEmp = findViewById(R.id.BotEmp);
    mBotDescubrir= findViewById(R.id.botDesc);
    mBotConectar = findViewById(R.id.botConectar);

    mLvEmparejados = findViewById(R.id.lvEmparejados);
    mLvDispositivos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDispositivos);
    //BT Adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    //Descubrir dispositivos
        //List adapter para recoger los dispositivos detectados
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    mLvDispositivos.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        //Check del estado del Bluetooth
    checkBluetoothState();
        //Registramos el receptor para la acción de recibir
    registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new 
    IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
    registerReceiver(devicesFoundReceiver, new 
    IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

    mLvDispositivos.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) AjustesConexionSensores.this);


    // Comprobar si el Bluetooth está disponible
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        mEstadoBlueTv.setText("Bluetooth no disponible.");
    } else {
        mEstadoBlueTv.setText("Bluetooth está disponible.");
    }

    // Establecer una imagen en función del estado del Bluetooth (on/off)
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mBluetIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_on);
    } else {
        mBluetIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.bt_off);
    }

    // Boton ON-OFF
    mBotOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           enableDisableBT();
        };
    });

    // Dispositivos emparejados
    mBotEmp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkBluetooth();
            bondedDevices();
        }
    });
    //Nuevos dispositivos
    mBotDescubrir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
               //Comprobamos que el coarse location esté permitido
               if (checkCoarseLocationPermission())
                    listAdapter.clear();
                    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
           } else {
               checkBluetoothState();
           }
        }
    });
    //Conectar a dispositivo
    mBotConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startConnection();
        }
    });
    //Hacemos check del permiso al iniciar la app
    checkCoarseLocationPermission();
 }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to handle `NavigationView` interaction in general? I mean, I'm not sure where you're at, exactly. I don't see any code for the `NavigationView`, and it seems like it only has the one menu item, so far.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be what your looking for specifically but, if you want to handle it by starting another activity and therefore, using another layout. You just need to set an intent and start an activity. You can all pass information from your activity to the new one an example of how to do this is below hope it helps.

```html
Intent myIntent = new Intent(myActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Extra_info", somefunction.extrainfo());//Pass extra info as a string
        myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        myActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);//Run the new activity
```